# Application of time reversal property of DFT

Tags: fourier-analysis

I came across the time reversal property of $DFT$ that states:

\begin{equation*}
x(<-n>_{N})\rightarrow X^{*}(k)
\end{equation*}

I can't seem to understand though how can this property be used practically, lets say in a case where you know a sequence $x(n)=\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ and its DFT $X(k)=\{e_{11},e_{22},e_{33}\}$ and you want to find the DFT of the sequence $x(-n)$.

Comment: Time reversal is not same as time shift.

Comment: Yes I know...I didn't realised that I had mentioned shifting in the title...I will correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Time reversal property states that if signal is reversed in time, the fourier coefficient is conjugate of $F(x[n])$ i.e $X(e^{(-j\omega)})$ or simply $X(-j\omega)$. (assuming real x[n])

So, if you mark fourier coefficients on a circle based on phase angle, $\omega$. To find coefficients of fourier transform of $x[n]$ you read anti-clockwise on circle and for $x[-n]$ clockwise

For the example you stated above DFT of $x[-n] = \bar{e11}, \bar{e22}, \bar{e33}$

Comment: So $X^{*}(k)$ will have the same elements as $X(k)$ but shifted?

Comment: I made a mistake in my notation please check again my previous comment. I obviously know about $x(n)$ and $x(-n)$.

Comment: $X^*(k)$ is conjugate of $X(k)$. $X(k)$ can be imaginary.

Comment: I know. In your answer you are talking about the $x(n)$ and $x(-n)$ and you don't even mention the $X(k)$ and $X^{*}(k)$.

Comment: Then what do $X(e^{-j\omega})$ mean ? or $X(e^{j\omega})$ mean ? 
Replace k by $j\omega$. This is another notation that is it.

Comment: <q>  
So $X^*(k)$ will have the same elements as $X(k)$ but shifted? </q>

$X^*(k)$ is conjugate of $X(k)$.

Answer (score 0):

To try explain it as simple as possible. You can think of it as mirroring each sine and cosine in the Fourier Transform in the middle point.

1. The cosines (real part of complex exponential) are even ($\cos(wx) = \cos(-wx)$), so they don't change.
2. The sines (imaginary part of complex exponential) are odd ($\sin(-wx) = -\sin(wx)$) so they will switch sign.

Therefore the imaginary part of each Fourier coefficient will switch sign but the real part will remain the same.